# what is the right verb for cleaning glasses with a cloth?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to mention the clear-eyed feeling of putting on recently wiped glasses. Is that correct? Or should I say, recently cleaned glasses? Is there a better option?

Comment: That reminds me to **wipe** my glasses, hee hee

Comment: Polished? I don't wear glasses, but that's what I'd go for anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a matter of preference, although *wiped* may imply the use of a *dry* cloth, whereas saying *cleaned* may imply the use of a wet cloth or cleaning solution.

Comment: When you have worn glasses as long as I have you have long since stopped wasting money on 'cleaning solutions'. Every optician will counsel you against using tissue to clean them, but it is the only thing I ever use and I have never in 53 years noticed any resultant deterioration in the lenses, even multi-focal, polychromic ones. So a bit of huff and a wipe with a tissue is all mine ever get.